# Concatenating variables in bash(debian)

Tags: bash, variables, concatenation

I have seen a number of ways how concatenation of variables are supposed to work but they are not working how I would expect and not sure why...  
I am reading a txt file into an array 
each row is a domain name I want to do an zone transfer output that to a file with the filename domain.zone simple right....

ok well here is the script I have commected out the actual dig part

```
#!/bin/bash
filecontent=($(cat goodFvzones.txt))
for t in "${filecontent[@]}"
do
n=".zone"
x=$t$n
echo "$x"
#dig @dnsserver -t axfr $t > $x
done
```

When I run the above script if the domainname it was working on was domain.com
what I get as output is:
    .zonen.com

Expected output would be domain.com.zone 
The content of variable n (5 charaters) is overwriting the first 5 charaters of variable t
Can someone explain what I am doing wrong I think it must have something to do with the period but have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you have `CR` characters in your text file? (Windows or Mac line endings)

Comment: That definitely sounds like the problem. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Use `filecontent=($(cat goodFvzones.txt | tr -d '\r'))` while waiting for @AntonKovalenko to suggest that as an answer.

Comment: Yes that was the problem I should have Known that Anton I actually used dos2unix to convert. But thanks for the other option that other guy.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yep, added as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you notice a shorter string "overwriting" the beginning of a longer string, the first thing to think of should be `CR` characters (used in Windows and Mac line endings). Command substitution removes newlines, but it removes *Unix* newlines (`LF`) and does nothing to carriage returns.

You can filter your input through `tr -d '\r'` to get rid of carriage returns, or use `dos2unix` utility to convert a broken file in-place.

Viewing your output with `less -U` can be helpful for debugging this kind of problems (`less -U` shows carriage returns, tabs and backspaces as control characters, like `^M` `^I` `^H`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a carriage return (\r) to IFS to make it just another whitespace character for argument parsing purposes:

```
IFS=$(printf "$IFS\r")
filecontent=($(cat goodFvzones.txt))
for t in "${filecontent[@]}"
do
  n=".zone"
  x=$t$n
  echo "$x"
  #dig @dnsserver -t axfr $t > $x
done
```